# Laravel 5.4 php artisan route:list showing incorrect data after a route:clear

Tags: laravel, routes

I have the following issue. I am running laravel 5.4 and have a problem with my routes, when I navigate to my `'/about-me'` of my predefined routes I get the error:

```
1/1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179:
```

However the route is defined as shows here:

`Route::get('about-me', function () {
    return view('about-me');
});`

On my view the link is pointing to that route as shown:

```
<a href="{{url('about-me')}}">About Me</a>
```

I have cleared my cached routes in SSH using the command:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

When I list my routes using the command:

```
`php artisan route:list`
```

I see an old version of my routes file. So this is the problem, however whatever I try they are not updating. I have cleared the cache locally and within laravel and still the old file file is showing when I type the `route:list` command.

I believe the code is all correct, however the new updated route file which contains the defined route for `about-me` is not being used. I have attached an image of the updated routes file on the server also.

Here is a link to the screenshot.  [Screenshot of route file on server](https://ibb.co/kHi1T5)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel 5.4 (or in earlier version, I'm not sure) routes has been moved to the separate folder in `app/routes/web.php` (as you can see here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel).

You can find routes registration in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L52)

Comment: Thanks! The problem was the laravel dev version I was using was not matching the version on the server i.e. it was 5.2. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to help :)